# How to remove \n or \t from a given string in C?

Tags: c, string

How can I strip a string with all \n and \t in C?

Answer (score 16):

This works in my quick and dirty tests. Does it in place:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strip(char *s) {
    char *p2 = s;
    while(*s != '\0') {
        if(*s != '\t' && *s != '\n') {
            *p2++ = *s++;
        } else {
            ++s;
        }
    }
    *p2 = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char buf[] = "this\t is\n a\t test\n test";
    strip(buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

And to appease Chris, here is a version which will make a place the result in a newly `malloc`ed buffer and return it (thus it'll work on literals). You will need to `free` the result.

```
char *strip_copy(const char *s) {
    char *p = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if(p) {
        char *p2 = p;
        while(*s != '\0') {
            if(*s != '\t' && *s != '\n') {
                *p2++ = *s++;
            } else {
                ++s;
            }
        }
        *p2 = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: It's rather unsafe to do this operation in place. What if the first line of `main()` changed to `char *buf = ...;` ? What if this was used in more convoluted code and the coders had forgotten which arguments were writable buffers and which weren't?

Comment: if you need to do it in a copy, then you can always make a copy first. Such code is still fairly simple.

Comment: @Lutz, I don't see how passing `char*` or `char[]` makes a difference.  Also, there's a bug in `strip`: the string isn't null-terminated.

Comment: @strager: he is consered about passing something like: `char *buf = "hello\tworld"` which is illegal because you can't modify a pointer to a literal. my `strip_copy` addresses that.

Comment: @strager - I don't think you could do that in C89. GCC on OS X won't let me do it in any mode.

Comment: But +1 for defying my expectation that strip-in-place would be inefficient.

Comment: @Chris: thanks :-). I've made an efficient version of strip_copy which (to my knowledge) does no more work than necessary ;).

Comment: It might be reuseful to also pass in the string "\t\n" as a parameter so you can reuse to strip other stuff

Comment: @gnibber - Then Evan would just be writing the function I outlined in my answer.

Comment: @Chris: indeed, we'll leave that one as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 5):

**If you want to replace \n or \t with something else**, you can use the function strstr(). It returns a pointer to the first place in a function that has a certain string. For example:

```
// Find the first "\n".
char new_char = 't';
char* pFirstN = strstr(szMyString, "\n");
*pFirstN = new_char;
```

You can run that in a loop to find all \n's and \t's.

**If you want to "strip" them, i.e. remove them from the string**, you'll need to actually use the same method as above, but copy the contents of the string "back" every time you find a \n or \t, so that "this i\ns a test" becomes: "this is a test".

You can do that with memmove (not memcpy, since the src and dst are pointing to overlapping memory), like so:

```
char* temp = strstr(str, "\t");
// Remove \n.
while ((temp = strstr(str, "\n")) != NULL) {
// Len is the length of the string, from the ampersand \n, including the \n.
     int len = strlen(str);
 memmove(temp, temp + 1, len); 
}
```

You'll need to repeat this loop again to remove the \t's.

**Note:** Both of these methods work in-place. **This might not be safe! (read Evan Teran's comments for details.**. Also, these methods are not very efficient, although they do utilize a library function for some of the code instead of rolling your own.

Comment: this looks like it would be very inefficient for a long string. You are searching the string (from the start) over and over again. In addition you are doing a strlen each and every time a char is found). Finally, you are copying the tail end of the string each time a char is found...

Comment: You're right, efficiency definitely wasn't a big concern (this is actually lifter straight from code I had lying around, which only worked with small strings). The strlen can actually be moved outside the string, I think, and the search can start each time from the last found location instead of the beginning, negating the "search every time problem". However, I don't see any way of removing the need to memmove, if he wants it done in place. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to see an efficient in place strip then take a look at my answer :-P.

Comment: Yep, I looked at it right after posting my comment, now I feel stupid :) At least now I have something to change in my project...

Comment: This is what I thought the answer was before I saw Evan's efficient version. +1 for library functions - `memmove()` is sadly relatively unknown.

Comment: I tried to use this approach but it failed miserably with clang's -fsanitize=address.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you have two ways to do this: you can create a copy of the original string, minus all `'\t'` and `'\n'` characters, or you can strip the string "in-place." However, I bet money that the first option will be faster, and I promise you it will be safer.

So we'll make a function:

```
char *strip(const char *str, const char *d);
```

We want to use [`strlen()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strlen.html) and [`malloc()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/malloc.html) to allocate a new `char *` buffer the same size as our `str` buffer. Then we go through `str` character by character. If the character is *not* contained in `d`, we copy it into our new buffer. We can use something like [`strchr()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strchr.html) to see if each character is in the string `d`. Once we're done, we have a new buffer, with the contents of our old buffer minus characters in the string `d`, so we just return that. I won't give you sample code, because this might be homework, but here's the sample usage to show you how it solves your problem:

```
char *string = "some\n text\t to strip";

char *stripped = strip(string, "\t\n");
```

Comment: +1 for providing all the information needed to learn **how** to do it. Odds are he's a beginner and this information will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a c string function that will find any character in `accept` and return a pointer to that position or NULL if it is not found.

```
#include <string.h>

char *strpbrk(const char *s, const char *accept);
```

Example:

```
char search[] = "a string with \t and \n";

char *first_occ = strpbrk( search, "\t\n" );
```

`first_occ` will point to the \t, or the 15 character in `search`.  You can replace then call again to loop through until all have been replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I like to make the standard library do as much of the work as possible, so I would use something similar to Evan's solution but with `strspn()` and `strcspn()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SPACE " \t\r\n"

static void strip(char *s);
static char *strip_copy(char const *s);

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char s[] = "this\t is\n a\t test\n test";
    char *s1 = strip_copy(s);
    strip(s);
    printf("%s\n%s\n", s, s1);
    return 0;
}

static void strip(char *s)
{
    char *p = s;
    int n;
    while (*s)
    {
        n = strcspn(s, SPACE);
        strncpy(p, s, n);
        p += n;
        s += n + strspn(s+n, SPACE);
    }
    *p = 0;
}

static char *strip_copy(char const *s)
{
    char *buf = malloc(1 + strlen(s));
    if (buf)
    {
        char *p = buf;
        char const *q;
        int n;
        for (q = s; *q; q += n + strspn(q+n, SPACE))
        {
            n = strcspn(q, SPACE);
            strncpy(p, q, n);
            p += n;
        }
        *p++ = '\0';
        buf = realloc(buf, p - buf);
    }
    return buf;
}
```