# How can I compare the received answer?

Tags: c, comparison

I have a simple echo server written in C, I would like to stop the server if it received the `quit` word

```
    int n;
    char buffer[256];
    while(strcmp(buffer,"quit") != 0)
    {
        n = read(sock,buffer,255);
        if (n < 0)
        {
        perror("ERROR reading from socket");
        exit(1);
        }

        printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
        printf("%d-%d\n", sizeof(buffer), strcmp(buffer,"quit"));

        n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);
        if (n < 0) 
        {
        perror("ERROR writing to socket");
        exit(1);
        }
  }
```

How can I compare the received buffer with a string?

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: @iUngi: .. where are you getting 1?

Comment: Try changing `"quit"` to `"quit\n"`? See also @cnicutar's answer!

Comment: could be a possible mistake that I'm using telnet to test the server?

Comment: You don't have any kind of protocol implemented, so you have no concept of a "message". Before you can have a "message" you have to define how messages are bounded and then you have to implement that  in code. (TCP is a byte-stream service and has no concept of a 'message'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
void strip(char *s) {
    char *p2 = s;
    while(*s != '\0') {
        if(*s != '\t' && *s != '\n' && *s != '\r') {
                *p2++ = *s++;
        } else {
                ++s;
        }
    }
    *p2 = '\0';
}
```

[How to remove \n or \t from a given string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515195/how-to-remove-n-or-t-from-a-given-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

It's likely the buffer isn't 0-terminated so using "string" comparison functions is wrong. You should try `strncmp` or `memcmp` instead.

Also, in the `while` condition, you're testing before actually reading into `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others said, your program's behavior is undefined: while entering the loop, you are reading from `buffer` before it's initialized.